# Image upload without page refresh and submit button

Tags: oracle-apex

I have form type region, inside it I have three sub regions: one for image upload, second for uploaded images data view and third for uploaded images view. It's possible to upload image to database without page refresh and how I can make it? An idea is when user filling form, he can upload images and when he uploads images, list of uploaded images is updates (with dynamic action).
I have idea to create a dynamic action for page item "file browser" with change event, but how to upload an image to database without submit I don't know. Another problems is that I don't want refresh page, because user can loose filled data and data from form have to go to one table, but images to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Dropzone plugin built for APEX is probably going to be your best option
https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-dropzone

This should be flexible enough to facilitate your non-submit needs, where it uploads into a collection after drag/drop, but before page submit.